# Error when update Aptana 3 to 3.0.9.201202141038

Tags: aptana, aptana3, auto-update

Error when update Aptana 3 to 3.0.9.201202141038, Detail:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.9.201202141038-14022012104032 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.9.201202141038-14022012104032)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1327114451399 (SharedProfile_AptanaProfile 1.0.0.1327114451399)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    toolingcom.aptana.rcp.product.rootfiles 3.0.9.201202141038-14022012104032
    toolingcom.aptana.rcp.product.rootfiles 3.0.8.201201201658-20012012170258
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1327114451399 (SharedProfile_AptanaProfile 1.0.0.1327114451399)
    To: toolingcom.aptana.rcp.product.rootfiles [3.0.8.201201201658-20012012170258]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.9.201202141038-14022012104032 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.9.201202141038-14022012104032)
    To: toolingcom.aptana.rcp.product.rootfiles [3.0.9.201202141038-14022012104032]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the suggestion in https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Errors+While+Updating#ErrorsWhileUpdating-%22Conflictingdependency%22.  Hope that helps.